# Eloquent Javascript ,Chapter 7 - Try catch throw

Tags: javascript

I understand it's trying to mimic break statement in a function and i have a basic understanding of "try catch".But i can't get my head around the process.

Here is the [link](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter7.html#p49342b38f17b6aca) .

I also don't understand the line underneath the code -

> if the action function throws Break, forEach will absorb the exception
>   and stop looping.

here is the actual code -

```
var Break = {toString: function() {return "Break";}};

function forEach(array, action) {
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      action(array[i]);
  }
  catch (exception) {
    if (exception != Break)
      throw exception;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: **That `forEach` is not the one in ES5** (I believe the book predates ES5). ES5's `Array#forEach` doesn't give you any way to break the loop early (that is, without the code calling `Array#forEach` seeing an exception); instead, you use `Array#some` or `Array#every` if you need to stop early. This note is just to keep folks from getting confused. The below is about the `forEach` in the OP's question, **not** ES5's.

---

In JavaScript, you can throw any value — an `Error` object, any other object, a number, a string, whatever.

What they're doing there is defining a specific object, `Break`, which they let you use as an exception to tell that `forEach` function to stop looping through the array.

If your iteration function throws that specific object `Break` object, the `forEach` will stop the loop but won't throw an exception. So the following doesn't throw, but stops at `2`:

```
forEach([1, 2, 3, 4], function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    if (entry === 2) {
        throw Break;
    }
});
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

But *this* will throw an exception (because numbers don't have a `doSomethingCool` method):

```
forEach([1, 2, 3, 4], function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    entry.doSomethingCool();
});
```

Output:

```
1
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The key to it is this pair of lines in the `catch`:

```
if (exception != Break)
  throw exception;
```

What that does is check whether what was thrown is the `Break` object (although it's not a very good check), and if it *wasn't*, it re-throws the exception so it shows up to the code calling `forEach`. But if it *is* the `Break` object, then it just silently stops the loop.

---

(The reason it's not a very good check is that if the exception is a string or number — and in JavaScript, they can be — it will do unnecessary work, doing type coercion to try to see if it can make the arguments match. It really should be `if (exception !== Break)` instead.)

---

**Tangent** (but it may help to illustrate what's going on a bit more): The design of this `forEach` variant isn't ideal from a performance perspective. Setting up a `try/catch` block is *cheap*, but it isn't free, and *throwing* an exception is ***expensive***. The alternative is to use the return value of the iterator function instead, like this:

```
var Break = {toString: function() {return "Break";}};

function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (action(array[i]) === Break) {
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

And then you could break the loop by *returning* the `Break` object:

```
forEach([1, 2, 3, 4], function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    if (entry === 2) {
        return Break;
    }
});
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Of course, that has the cost of doing a comparison on the return value of the iterator on each iteration. The cost of doing that is quite similar to setting up the `try/catch` block, but cheaper on most engines.

But is there really any speed difference with modern engines?

Yes. There's a difference both in the case where we *don't* break the loop, and a **huge** difference in the case where we do:

Here's the case where we are *not* breaking the loop (we don't `throw` or `return` the `Break` object, so the loop completes): [Test Case](http://jsperf.com/throwing-vs-returning)

[image: bar graph showing using return faster on most engines when not breaking loop]

The difference is fairly minor, with all engines except Firefox's SpiderMonkey giving the `return` (with comparison) version the edge. But again, whichever way they go, the costs are similar.

But here's the version where we *do* break the loop: [Test Case](http://jsperf.com/throwing-vs-returning/2)

[image: bar graph showing using return dramatically faster on all engines when breaking loop]

As you can see, it's ***dramatically*** better to `return Break;` than to `throw Break;`